# how to split the code so that it runs on two computers

Tags: python-2.7, split, ros

I 'd like to split the code into two parts so that part of it runs on my PC and another part run on the Intel board (computer of the robot) at the same time and connects between them using WiFi. my issue: I am running the code for vision-based tracking and map using lidar data. As a result, the frame per second is low and the robot's movement is not smooth. So, I'd like to run the code vision-based tracking on my PC and another part based on lidar data on the computer of the robot.

if it is possible. Please help me or any suggestions and what are its disadvantages?.

Comment: You will need to use sockets to communicate between the two. Here is a good overview of what that might look like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352855/communication-between-two-computers-using-python-socket. You may run into firewall or proxy issues, but maybe not if they're on the same wifi. I'd recommend getting the communication to work on the same machine via `localhost` and then try connecting to external `ip`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you could run the vision-based part of the system in your PC and the movement functionality in the robot. Assuming that you have the code parts running in individual nodes, you can follow this guide [Running ROS over multiple computers](https://github.com/ut-ims-robotics/tutorials/wiki/Running-ROS-over-multiple-computers) or the [official guide](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines) and set up your system.

Doing that the onboard computer will handle the low-level stuff and the PC the computationally demanding part (+ rviz).

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help. I will start to use it immediately.

Comment: I got some error, could you help me, please? https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/1840

Comment: Hello, it might be a good idea to open a new question for that. However, just a hint. When I want to exchange arrays of floats (personally) I use a std_msgs structure called [Float32MultiArray](http://docs.ros.org/api/std_msgs/html/msg/Float32MultiArray.html)

Comment: I opened it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58950233/class-struct-error-required-argument-is-not-a-float-when-writing-data